# Enable Shift-Multiselect in jQuery UI Selectable for div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i found multiple answers for selecting elements with ui selectable here but none of them help me to select multiple div instead of li so can anyone help me with same. all i want is to select multiple div in row with shift key event.
thanks for comments and answers in advance

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default works with CTRL not SHIFT.

Comment: it works on list but i want same to work on div instead of list

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mac2000/DJFaL/1/embedded/result/

i want the same but instead of ul or li it shall work on a div in which i can select its children div instead of li

Comment: also i would like to mention that the above fiddle is a reference i took from an answer on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or META Key.

> On Macintosh keyboards, the META key maps to the Command key (⌘).
>
> On Windows keyboards, the META key maps to the Windows key.

jQuery UI Selectable works on pretty much any proper structure. If you want to use `<div>` you can, you just need a wrapper and children.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable div {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="selectable">
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

If you want to allow specific items, use the `filter` options.

> **filter**
>
> Type: Selector
>
> Default: `"*"`
>
> The matching child elements will be made selectees (able to be selected).

If you examine the code, you will see that in `_mouseStart`, it is specifically written to look for Ctrl or Meta keys:

```
if ( !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey ) {
```

If you *really* want to use the Shift key, you can use the Widget Factory (`$.widget()`) to clone selectable and re-write the `_mouseStart` function to also make an exception for `!event.shiftKey` as well.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.shiftSelect", $.ui.selectable, {
    _mouseStart: function(event) {
      var that = this,
        options = this.options;

      this.opos = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
      this.elementPos = $(this.element[0]).offset();

      if (this.options.disabled) {
        return;
      }

      this.selectees = $(options.filter, this.element[0]);

      this._trigger("start", event);

      $(options.appendTo).append(this.helper);

      // position helper (lasso)
      this.helper.css({
        "left": event.pageX,
        "top": event.pageY,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      });

      if (options.autoRefresh) {
        this.refresh();
      }

      this.selectees.filter(".ui-selected").each(function() {
        var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
        selectee.startselected = true;
        if (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
          that._removeClass(selectee.$element, "ui-selected");
          selectee.selected = false;
          that._addClass(selectee.$element, "ui-unselecting");
          selectee.unselecting = true;

          // selectable UNSELECTING callback
          that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
            unselecting: selectee.element
          });
        }
      });

      $(event.target).parents().addBack().each(function() {
        var doSelect,
          selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
        if (selectee) {
          doSelect = (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) ||
            !selectee.$element.hasClass("ui-selected");
          that._removeClass(selectee.$element, doSelect ? "ui-unselecting" : "ui-selected")
            ._addClass(selectee.$element, doSelect ? "ui-selecting" : "ui-unselecting");
          selectee.unselecting = !doSelect;
          selectee.selecting = doSelect;
          selectee.selected = doSelect;

          // selectable (UN)SELECTING callback
          if (doSelect) {
            that._trigger("selecting", event, {
              selecting: selectee.element
            });
          } else {
            that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
              unselecting: selectee.element
            });
          }
          return false;
        }
      });

    }
  });
  
  $("#selectable").shiftSelect();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable div {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="selectable">
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes but can i select a sequence of div for example if i select one div with shift and than without releasing shift i select another div than it shall select all div in between them

Comment: @cyrus It is not written to use SHIFT; you have to use CTRL key. Yes, you can select some and then when holding CTRL select more items.

Comment: please check the fiddle i provide they have use a shift instead and the only thing is that i want the exact but on divs

Comment: @cyrus if you like that sort of thing, you can go ahead and use it.

Comment: @cyrus updated my answer with what I would advise doing. It's a lot loftier; yet I hope it's more robust.

Comment: @cyrus You can Copy/Paste the code above into a fiddle if you need.